# Nesting Marionette regions, layouts and views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to get my Marionette views working in combination with application regions and layouts, but I just can't seem to get the nested views in the layout to render.

**Edit:** I expected both the `OptionsView` and `BreadcrumbsView` to be rendered in the `NavigationLayout`, which should be rendered in the navigation region. However, the navigation region isn't rendered at all. The console doesn't show any errors.

My structure is as follows:

```
- Navigation region
  - Navigation layout
    - Options region 
    - Breadcrumbs region
- Content region
```

Assigning an `ItemView` to the navigation region works as expected.

```
App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
App.addRegions({
    'nav': '#nav',
    'content': '#content'
});

var NavigationLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#nav-template',
    regions: {
        'breadcrumbs': '#breadcrumbs',
        'options': '#options'
    }
});

var BreadcrumbsView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#breadcrumbs-template'
});

var OptionsView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#options-template'
});

var ContentView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#content-template'
});

App.addInitializer(function(options) {
    var navigationLayout = new NavigationLayout();

    App.nav.show(navigationLayout);
    App.content.show(new ContentView());

    navigationLayout.breadcrumbs.show(new BreadcrumbsView());
    navigationLayout.options.show(new OptionsView());
});

$(function() {
    App.start();
});
```

A reduced test case can be found [here](http://pastie.org/4889632)

Comment: There's not enough info to know what's going on. What errors are you getting, if any? What behavior are you seeing vs what were you expecting?

Comment: are you using Marionette.Async? or any other code in here that runs async?

Comment: No, the code above is all the Javascript in this test case, together with the latest release of jQuery, Underscore, Backbone and Marionette. I updated the link to the entire test, pastebin.com seemed to be down.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, finally found the problem: You can't name a region `options` in a layout.

All of the regions that are defined in a Layout are directly attached to the layout instance. So, a region defined like this:

```
Layout.extend({
  regions: {
    options: "#options"
  }
});
```

ends up setting the `layoutInstance.options` to the Region instance. This is a problem because Backbone.View defines and uses the `options` for other purposes.

Renaming the region to anything other than an existing keyword or attribute used by any existing view will fix this.

```
Layout.extend({
  regions: {
    optionRegion: "#options"
  }
});
```

Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tegon/64ovLf64/

Comment: How does your example know where to append the HTML to? I'm having trouble getting a grip on how layouts are rendered to the DOM without having to use .html() or .append()? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658403/rendering-layouts-and-sub-views-in-marionette-backbone-js

Comment: @streetlignt You probably figured this out by now, but, you use a templating system. underscore and handlebars are two that are commonly used.