# MarionetteJS nested views

Tags: javascript, layout, backbone.js, marionette

I have yet another question concerning the Backbone.Marionette framework.

**Background**
After reading through the Github docs, and working on an own [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/teSZSh8548HzCy3H3IRO?p=preview) (still in progress). I had decided to take a step back and see how to best implement nested views. This has led to to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662712/nesting-marionette-regions-layouts-and-views) among other things.

**The problem [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GY5IT8?p=preview)** Although this did help me to create a layout, using a single container to display the menu layout, I did not manage to render a layout *within* a layout. At this point I'm not sure if this is possible at all. But with a large web application it would not seem uncommon to me to have nested layouts?

I get the following error while running the example: `TypeError: view is undefined`. This happens when I try to render the views when the application starts. At the moment I'm not competely sure on how to do this.

I hope anyone has some more experience ragrding this subject. I'm fairly new to the framework. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the error is because you are calling `show` on your layout view but not passing it a view to show:

```
contentLayout.left.show();
contentLayout.right.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing a silly mistake! For everybody reading this, the solution is simply the following: `contentLayout.left.show( new LeftView() );
contentLayout.right.show( new RightView() );`